# Storing user roles in a json file

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so i want to make a mute command that whenever you use it, it will store user's roles and then take them from the user that is been muted, after the mute time ends it will give the roles back

i can't think a way of doing that and i am not that experienced in discord bot codding
the problem is i can't find a way storing user roles in a json file and then giving them back

sorry for the small amount of information

```
const target = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()); 
    
    if(command == 'warn'){
            if(!target || !args[0].startsWith("<@")) return message.reply('');
          //  if(target.id == message.author.id) return message.reply('');
        //  if(target.id == botID) return message.reply('');
           const time = args[1];
            if(!time) return message.reply('');

            

        if(!message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.cache.has(warnRole) 
        && !message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.cache.has(warn2Role)){
            message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.add(warnRole);
            message.reply("<@" + target + ">" + " " + ms(ms(time)));

            setTimeout(function(){
                target.roles.remove(warnRole);
                message.channel.send("<@" + target + ">" + "");
            }, ms(time));

        }else if(message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.cache.has(warnRole)) {
            message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.add(warn2Role);
            message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.remove(warnRole);
            message.reply("<@" + target + ">" + " " + ms(ms(time)));

            setTimeout(function(){
                target.roles.remove(warn2Role);
                message.channel.send("<@" + target + ">" + " ");
            }, ms(time));

        }else if(message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.cache.has(warn2Role)){

                message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.add(warn2Role);
                message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.add(muteRole);
            message.reply("<@" + target + ">" + "  " + ms(ms(time)));

            setTimeout(function(){
                target.roles.remove(muteRole);
                target.roles.add(targetroles);
                message.channel.send("<@" + target + ">" + " ");
            }, ms(time));

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use a database.

Comment: i don't know how to use one can you suggest me a tutorial or something

Comment: I don't know of any specific tutorials that I could suggest to you, but if you just look up "how to use a database in javascript" you'll find thousands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in fs module to write to json files. (just add `const fs = require('fs')` to the top of your script)

You can first start with an json file like:

```json
{
   "muted": [{
      "id": "idoftheuser",
      "rolesremoved": ["roleid#1", "roleid#2"]
   }]
}
```

When your mute thing is called, you can read in the file with fs by doing

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./mute.json') //I'm assuming you're putting this in the same folder as your main bot file
let parsed = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

With this you can just push in the new user into the `muted` array and then write the data back to the file

```js
parsed.muted.push(newmuted) //newmuted is the object of whoever you're muting, using the template in the json above
let newraw = JSON.stringify(parsed);
fs.writeFileSync(newraw);
```